# Why MVC5 gives this error "The requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS' "?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have updated my application from MVC4 to MVC5, when I run it with MVC4 it works fine but for MVC5 it gives error `{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS'."}`  in FIDDLER.

1)
**REQUEST TO APPLICATION OF MVC5 in Fiddler : **

```
OPTIONS /api/Controller/Method HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://wyx.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: referer, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: exampleImage.gif
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

**RESPONSE OF MVC5 APPLICATION in Fiddler : **

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
**Allow: POST**
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Date: Mon, 10 Mar 2014 13:32:48 GMT
Content-Length: 76
```

2)
** REQUEST TO APPLICATION OF MVC4 in Fiddler **

```
OPTIONS /api/Controller/Method HTTP/1.1
Host:  example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://wyx.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: referer, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: exampleImage.gif
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

**RESPONSE OF MVC5 APPLICATION in Fiddler : **

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
**Allow: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST**
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Public: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Date: Mon, 10 Mar 2014 13:54:08 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Why in MVC4 **Allow** is "
**Allow**: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
And in MVC5 :
**Allow**: POST

I also tried in MVC5 in web.config ::

```
 <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      </modules>
    <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
            <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />

          </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Any update on this? Are you still having the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your api initializer and verify that you have

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

instead of

```
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

This actually fixed the exact same issue for me. The errors actually indicate that your routes are not set up at all ;)